# SQL Select any other records if exist and select default if no others

Tags: sql, oracle

I wish to select any other multiple records if it exists (not including the value 9999) - if NO other records exist except one with the value 9999 then only must that one be returned.

In other words, imagine the following:

```
  | FIELD1 | FIELD2 | FIELD3 |
1.|  AAA   | BBB    | 1234   |
2.|  AAA   | BCB    | 1234   |
3.|  AAA   | ABB    | 1234   |
4.|  AAA   | BDB    | 9999   |
5.|  AAA   | SDD    | 1234   |
```

So, I only want row 1,2,3 and 5 where FIELD1 = 'AAA' and NOT row 4. IF no other rows existed where FIELD1 = 'AAA' and FIELD3 = '9999' then it should return only that one.

Comment: The tag `sql` is not enough. Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've got it right:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TestTable as T
WHERE 
(
  (Field3 <>9999) 
  OR
  ( 
    (Field3 = 9999) 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TestTable 
                 WHERE Field1 = T.Field1 AND Field3 <>9999)
   ) 
 );
```

For the table:

```
AAA BBB 1234
AAA BCB 1234
AAA ABB 1234
AAA BDB 9999
AAA SDD 1234
BBB BDB 9999
CCC BBB 1234
CCC BCB 1234
CCC ABB 1234
CCC BDB 9999
CCC SDD 1234
```

Output will be:

```
AAA BBB 1234
AAA BCB 1234
AAA ABB 1234
AAA SDD 1234
BBB BDB 9999
CCC BBB 1234
CCC BCB 1234
CCC ABB 1234
CCC SDD 1234
```

Comment: Works like a dream!

Comment: Thank you, so much!

Comment: @valex You could remove that exists clause; it's a bit pointless because if you have a row with the field3 != 9999 then you automatically know that a row with field3 != 9999 exists in the table for that field1! That will reduce the number of calls to the table to 2, rather than 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `UNION` and `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.field3 <> 9999
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM YourTable s
WHERE s.field3 = 9999
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable p
                 WHERE p.field1 = s.field1
                   AND s.field2 <> 9999)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table( FIELD1 VARCHAR(100), FIELD2 VARCHAR(100) ,FIELD3 INT)
INSERT INTO #Table( FIELD1 , FIELD2  ,FIELD3)
SELECT 'AAA','BBB',1234 UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA','BCB',1234 UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA','ABB',1234 UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA','BDB',9999 UNION ALL
SELECT 'AAA','SDD',1234   

SELECT * FROM #Table T1
WHERE FIELD3 = (SELECT FIELD3 FROM #Table T2 GROUP BY FIELD3 HAVING COUNT(*)     
> 1)
```

Comment: No results will be returned if only a 9999 record exists

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer.

---

#### Option 1

```
select      *

from        t

where       field3 <> 9999
         or not exists (select null from t t2 where t2.field1 = t.field1 and field3 <> 9999)
;
```

#### Option 2

```
select      *

from       (select      *
                       ,min (case when field3 <> 9999 then 1 end) over 
                                (partition by field1)    as field3_no_9999_flag

            from        t
            )

where       field3              <> 9999
        or  field3_no_9999_flag is null            
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER then you can achive this using IF ELSE, I name your table as TAB, Please change accordingly.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT FIELD3 FROM TAB WHERE FIELD3=9999)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE FIELD3=9999
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TAB
END
```

Comment: Even if the OP uses SQL Server, which is not clear at this point, using T-SQL where a SQL can be used is a problematic path

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which only accesses the table once, but uses an analytic function:

```
WITH testtable AS (SELECT 'AAA' field1, 'BBB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'AAA' field1, 'BCB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'AAA' field1, 'ABB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'AAA' field1, 'BDB' field2, 9999 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'AAA' field1, 'SDD' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'BBB' field1, 'BDB' field2, 9999 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'CCC' field1, 'BBB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'CCC' field1, 'BCB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'CCC' field1, 'ABB' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'CCC' field1, 'SDD' field2, 1234 field3 FROM dual)
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       field3
FROM   (SELECT field1,
               field2,
               field3,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN field3 != 9999 THEN field3 END) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) cnt_non_default
        FROM   testtable)
WHERE  field3 != 9999
OR     cnt_non_default = 0;

FIELD1 FIELD2     FIELD3
------ ------ ----------
AAA    BBB          1234
AAA    BCB          1234
AAA    ABB          1234
AAA    SDD          1234
BBB    BDB          9999
CCC    BBB          1234
CCC    BCB          1234
CCC    ABB          1234
CCC    SDD          1234
```

This may or may not be more performant than the other suggested answers which access the table twice or more - you'd need to test against your table and (a suitable amount of) data to see which works best for you.